# 'Some libraries imported but unused' warning in Spyder with scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder

I get an error about scikit-learn and others, "Some libraries imported but unused", when I want to run my code.

```
conda version : 4.6.14
python version : 3.7.3.final.0
```

Error output:

> math imported but unused
>
> sklearn.metrics..... imported but unused
>
> random imported but unused

Same warning all below up this libraries.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a warning is **NOT** an error. A warning is a warning.

Your IDE, by doing [Static Code Analysis](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/pylint.html) is just warning you that you are importing libraries that you are not using in your code. Considered as bad practices, your IDE is implicitly suggesting to remove those lines of code.